# stm32f4 write/read 16bits into two 8-bit gpio port

Tags: stm32, gpio

I try to write 16 bit data into two selected 8-bits gpio ports . I must split data for
LSB and MSB :

```
void LCD_write_command(uint16_t cmd) {
    GPIOD->ODR = cmd & 0x00ff; //lsb
    GPIOA->ODR = (GPIOA->ODR & 0x00ff) | (cmd >> 8); //msb
}
```

and read data :

```
uint16_t LCD_read_data(void) {
    (here is instruct gpio as input)
    volatile uint16_t data = 0;
    data  = (uint16_t)GPIOD->IDR & 0x00ff; //lsb
    data |= (uint16_t)GPIOA->IDR << 8 ; // msb
    (here is instruct gpio as output)
    return data;
}
```

When i use one 16bit gpio to write and read everything is fine:

```
 void LCD_write_command(uint16_t cmd) {
    GPIOD->ODR = cmd & 0xffff; 
}
uint16_t LCD_read_data(void) {
    volatile uint16_t data = 0;
    data  = (uint16_t)GPIOD->IDR & 0xffff; 
    return data;
}
```

I relay dont know what im missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wtite_bits(uint16_t cmd)
{
    uint32_t data = GPIOA -> ODR;

    data &= ~(0x1fff);
    data |= cmd & 0x1fff;
    GPIOA -> ODR = data;

    data = GPIOB -> ODR;
    data &= ~(0x0007);
    data |= (cmd & 0x8fff) >> 13;
    GPIOB -> ODR = data;
}
```

preserve other bits in the register

Comment: This is ok, but allows for read modify write errors. With the IO in the STMs, you're better using the BSRR registers for atomic bit sets and resets.

Comment: This is the LCD,  atomicity is not the issue here :). And another problem - OP has a problem with the simple bitwise operations. He needs something simple.

Comment: Colin__S : I use atomic in HAL library for stm32f4 .LCD isn't atomic ( very cheap LCD for aliex....)
.PeterJ :thanks to you i think : Now i dont have bitwise oper problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn a bit more about bitwise operations.

1. Writing

   ```
   void LCD_write_command(uint16_t cmd) {
      uint32_t tmp = GPIOD->ODR;

      tmp &= ~(0xff);
      tmp |= (cmd & 0x00ff);  
      GPIOD->ODR = tmp; //lsb
      tmp = GPIOA->ODR;
      tmp &= ~(0xff);
      tmp |= (cmd >> 8);
      GPIOA->ODR = tmp; //msb
   }
   ```

or

```
void LCD_write_command(uint16_t cmd) {
   *(volatile uint8_t *)&GPIOD->ODR = cmd & 0xff;
   *(volatile uint8_t *)&GPIOA->ODR = cmd >> 8; //msb
}
```

forcing the compiler to use 8 bit store instructions.

Before using non word access to the registers check in the RM if your micro allows it:
[image]

Comment: Tht means that you have wrong conection when you connect to two ports. No miracles.

Comment: Yeah i know . I even check that ports and pins isn't broken.I've triple check  connections and hardware port its ok .I must reaped  that when i use whole 16 gpios of one port every thing is fine

Answer (score 0):

Non of yours sugested code works for me , below is original source code of handling with LCD:

```
void LCD_write_command(uint16_t cmd) {
    GPIOB->BRR = LCD_CS;       // LCD_CS low (chip select pull)
    GPIOB->BRR = LCD_RS;       // LCD_RS low (register select = instruction)
    //GPIOA->ODR = cmd;         // put cmd to PortA (full length)
    // put cmd [0..12] bits to PortA (actual LCD_DB00..LCD_DB12)
    // put cmd [13..15] bits to PortB (actual LCD_DB13..LCD_DB15)
    GPIOA->ODR = cmd & 0x1fff;
    GPIOB->ODR = (GPIOB->ODR & 0xfff8) | (cmd >> 13);
    GPIOB->BRR = LCD_WR;       // pull LCD_WR to low (write strobe start)
    // Write strobe 66ns long by datasheet. GPIO speed on STM32F103 at 72MHz slower -> delay is unnecessary
    // asm volatile ("nop");
    GPIOB->BSRR = LCD_WR;      // pull LCD_WR to high (write strobe end)
    GPIOB->BSRR = LCD_CS;      // LCD_CS high (chip select release)
}
```

I've checked RM and i can operate on 8-bit ,half word and word.

Comment: It is not 8/8bits. It is another case.

Comment: yeah but what its difrent when you use 13/3 bit if you operate at &00ff (that means half word ).Procedure its same.

Comment: the code is not doing what you actually think it should

Comment: I have checked once again wiring .Everything was connected correctly but ONE wire seems to be broken -when i put Hi into that wire  i have at end of it 2,8V but if  put low i have 1,25V . Change one wire and now works fine . 
Thanks Peter ! your code works beter than my .Now i understand bitwise

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem: need to write some bits to port at same time.
My output bits are on port B: 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 (see missing bit 3).

It is possible to read whole port (`ODR`), and/or bits and write it back.

Faster version is to set all bits:
`GPIOB ->BSRR =0b00000000000000000000001111111011;`

and then clear only ones needed:
`GPIOB ->BRR =some_bits_to_clear;`

It was like some custom 74LS154 chip.

Or even try to clear and set bits at same time using:
`GPIOB ->BSRR =bits_to clear<<16 | bits_to_set;`

Depending on situation, there are many ways to optimize code.

Comment: Also, check if your LCD can be mapped as FSMC device. Then all data to LCD can be transfered as simple "write to RAM" and "read from RAM" operation.
`*(__IO unsigned char *)(LCD_DAT_ADDR)=d;
d=*(__IO unsigned char *)(LCD_DAT_ADDR);`